# Scala Futures in For Comprehension

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I'm trying to wrap my head around Scala and I'm wondering what the following does:

```
val fFuture: Future[Int] = Future { println("f called"); 3 }                                                                                                                    
val gFuture: Future[Int] = Future { println("g called"); 4 }                                                                                                                    

for {
    f <- fFuture
    g <- gFuture
} yield f
```

The futures are executed inside of the for comprehension, correct? So what does `f` do in the yield statement? Does that just mean it's available? Is that considered the `return value` if this were inside of a function?

Comment: The `Future` are not executed inside the `for`. They are executed when declared (always), and there composed using the `for`.

Comment: @cchantep Technically they are only executed when the ExecutionContext decides to execute them.

Comment: Right I should've said, executed at one time decided by the EC, since their declarations, so possibly (what's important there) between declaration and before the `for`, with no predictable order as these `Future`s are not depending on each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The futures are starting to execute here:

```
val fFuture: Future[Int] = Future { println("f called"); 3 }                                                                                                                    
val gFuture: Future[Int] = Future { println("g called"); 4 }
```

So both executions are starting in parallel. However if you accidentally put `Future{...}` inside for-comprehension - they gonna be executed sequentially.

For-comprehension basically subscribes and merges two results into one Future. However, in your case it seems like second future's result was ignored, which doesn't makes sense. The code that makes sense:

```
for {
    f <- fFuture
    g <- gFuture
} yield f + g
```

This code returns `Future[Int]`(same as code in your example). If you extract value from this Future - you get `3 + 4 = 7`. However it's still not a best approach as your computations are independent and probability of developer's mistake (stated above) that makes them sequential is still high, so recommended approach for independent computations is:

```
(fFuture zip gFuture) map {
  case (f, g) => f + g
}
```

This code is referentially transparent in meaning that even if you replace `fFuture` with `Future{...}` - it still behaves same (in case of `Future` -they're going to be executed in prallel, but it might be different for other concurrency primitives)

Where would `for-comprehension` actually make sense? Here:

```
for {
    f <- Future{... 9}
    g <- if (f > 0) Future{...} else Future{...}
} yield g
```

As `g` depends on `f` here - there is no way to run those in parallel, so `for` provides a non-blocking way of composing several `Future`s

Answer (score 1):

Scala Futures are evaluated eagerly, which means that their value is immediately calculated in a separate thread.

When you run operations that depend on result of the future, the current thread is going to block waiting until it becomes evaluated. If you transform Futures using combinator methods such as map or flatMap, you are getting another Future that represents the end result (the code running these operations doesn't need to block).

So in your example the for comprehension is desugared by the compiler to the following expression:

```scala
fFuture.flatMap(f => gFuture.map(g => f + g))
```

Which itself is a Future[Int] calculated in another thread.

Answer (score -2):

Here in your scenario, you dont have to use for comprehension, you can simply use OnComplete.

```
ffuture.OnComplete {
Case Success(result) => println(s"$result')
Case Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace
}
```

For Comprehension is needed when you have future(s) dependent on other future(s)
like:

```
var result =  for {
        f <- fFuture
        g <- f
    } yield g
```

Here g future will be resolved after f completes,
and yield will return whatever is the result you are returning. In this case it will be a Future[Int].
With yield you can do things like.

```
yield g+f
```

To read the result you can simply use

```
result.onSuccess or onComplete
```

For Futures, I found this article as the best one:
http://alvinalexander.com/scala/concurrency-with-scala-futures-tutorials-examples

I will say yes, this is similar to return value in a function.
But this is for comprehension syntax, you cant use return statement with it.
For comprehension is a better way to write map.

Comment: It would be great help if you can explain the reason of dislike, i will learn something new.